# jQuery validate before page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when I click submit it directs to error page. I'd like to validate before it redirects to error page, the plugin works like that. Is there a way to prevent the submission if there was something wrong with the user's input ?

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-contact" class="button" value="Send" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function() {

        var name = $('input#name').val();
        if (name == ""){
            $('#name').addClass('errro');
            return false;}
        else {
            $('#name').removeClass('errro');}

    });
});
```

Comment: I see where you get your name `questionMonster`, you've butchered this question. Can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several minutes of staring at the question I think I know what you mean. You can do that by listening for the `submit` event and returning `false` when you think that there's something wrong with the user's input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#theForm").submit(function() {

        var name = $('input#name').val();
        if (name == ""){
            $('#name').addClass('errro');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#name').removeClass('errro');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

input type="submit" name="submit-contact" class="button" onClick="Somejavascriptfunction" value="Send"

function Somejavascriptfunction()
{
Retrieve Username and password via $(".Username").val() and $(".Password").val()
Pass it to a ajax request page.
Get result back from ajax page.
If invalid then pop up message via jquery 
if valid then submit.
}

AjaxPage
{
Do the verification(1. Empty username/password 2. Correct username and password..etc)
Return result back to calling function
}